# Elmah and Entity Framework DropCreateDatabaseAlways

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, elmah

I have an application using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework 6.

Currently I use DropCreateDatabaseAlways database initializer in local for easier testing and debugging. I want to config the application to use Elmah to log exceptions but haven't been succeeded. Ideally I want Elmah logs in a separate database from existing application database. Here are what I tried so far:

1. Install Elmah and Elmah.Mvc from Nuget
2. In web.config, add errorLog section to specify connection string to Elmah (not created yet)

   ```
   <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="ElmahConnection" />
   ```
3. Add another connection string for Elmah in web.config:

   ```
   <connectionStrings>    
   <add name="OTEConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OTE.mdf;Initial Catalog=OTE;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="ElmahConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Elmah.mdf;Initial Catalog=Elmah;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   ```

OTEConnection is my existing connection string for Entity Framework. 
When I run this, I got error:

```
Cannot attach the file '{AbsolutePath}\App_Data\Elmah.mdf' as database 'Elmah'.
```

Anyone knows why I have this error? If it's not possible to have Elmah to be in separate database, how should I create Elmah table every time Entity Framework drops and creates a new database? I guess I'll need to create a new class inheriting from DropCreateDatabaseAlways and override method InitializeDatabase?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally solve by creating a custom class to execute script to create table for Elmah when DropCreateDatabaseAlways is called (based on answer from here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a0e09e12-4530-4148-a937-48d9bbf25a47/get-aspnet-membershiprole-working-with-dropcreatedatabasealways?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

```
    public class ElmahDbInitializer
{        
    public static void RunScript()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OTEConnection"].ConnectionString);

        string scriptText = GetScript();
        string[] commandTexts = GetScriptSections(scriptText);
        Array.ForEach(commandTexts, s => RunSection(s, con));
    }

    private static string GetScript()
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(GetExecutingDirectory() + "\\SetUp\\ELMAH-1.2-db-SQLServer.sql"))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }            
    }

    private static string GetExecutingDirectory()
    {
        string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    }

    private static string[] GetScriptSections(string scriptText)
    {
        //split the script on "GO" commands
        string[] splitter = new string[] { "\r\nGO\r\n" };
        string[] commandTexts = scriptText.Split(splitter,
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        return commandTexts;
    }

    private static void RunSection(string commandText, SqlConnection con)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, con))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```